# Grouping a repetitive section starting and end on a specific format/word

Tags: python, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to capture a multiline string which start at a specific word `Case` and end with a date with format `dd.mm.yyyy` OR `dd.m.dddd`

**Here is sample text:**

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda
asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane
asd - (one two three four).
Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda
asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane
asd - (one two three four).
Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda
asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane
asd - (one two three four).
Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda
asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane
asd - (one two three four).
Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

**I am trying this:**

**Flags:** `g m i`

```
^case[^]*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}
^case[\s\S]*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}
((^case)[\s\S]+(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}))
```

*note: case insensitive flag is set*

I am expecting to get group of each paragraph `(case - date)`.

These expressions capture the only one group with first **case** to last **date**

**Case** No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date .........29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date .........29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date .........29.8.1818

Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii) sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date .........**29.8.1818**

I am investigating newline and lookarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flags=re.DOTALL|re.M` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LPBwh3/1)):

```
data = '''Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.2 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.3 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818

Case No.X.4 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818'''

import re

for m in re.findall(r'^Case.*?\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}$', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M):
    print(m)
    print('-' * 160)
```

Prints:

```
Case No.X.1 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case No.X.2 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case No.X.3 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case No.X.4 I know I am a lucky boy (1) a sda asddasd (ii)
sa asdas asd aklk Railway, Airplane asd - (one two three four). Closing date ......... 29.8.1818
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You are a Superhero! Thank for your help!